# Java Generic: Why compiler can not resolve type T to inherited type in method?

Tags: java, generics

I've got classes

```
public class DiaryItem extends AbstractInfoElement { ... };

public class EventItem extends AbstractInfoElement { ... };

public class StickerItem extends AbstractInfoElement { ... };

public class TodoItem extends AbstractInfoElement { ... };
```

I've got overridden methods to do something with this parameters:

```
class DBEngine {

    public long add(EventItem item){ ... };

    public long add(StickerItem item){ ... };

    public long add(TodoItem item){ ... }

}
```

Then I realized template class to manipulate types in generic way

```
public class AddItemCommand<T extends AbstractInfoElement>{

    private final T item;

    public AddItemCommand(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    void doSmth() {
      add(item);
    }
}
```

I suppose compiler resolve T as needed type, but I got issues:

```
Error:(78, 45) error: no suitable method found for add(T)
method DBEngine.add(DiaryItem) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; T cannot be converted to DiaryItem)
method DBEngine.add(EventItem) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; T cannot be converted to EventItem)
method DBEngine.add(StickerItem) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; T cannot be converted to StickerItem)
method DBEngine.add(TodoItem) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; T cannot be converted to TodoItem)
where T is a type-variable:
T extends AbstractInfoElement declared in class AddItemCommand
```

My goal was to avoid overcoding in those cases:

```
AddItemCommand<DiaryItem> cmdDiary = new AddItemCommand<DiaryItem>(new DiaryItem);
cmdDiary.doSmth();
```

should call

```
DBEngine.add(DiaryItem item);
```

and

```
AddItemCommand<TodoItem> cmdTodo = new AddItemCommand<TodoItem>(new TodoItem);
cmdTodo.doSmth();
```

should call

```
DBEngine.add(TodoItem item);
```

That's all, but doesn't work ... Those issues are at compile time...

*BTW... Excuse my poor english*

Comment: This question is lacking some relevant code and information. Where do you get the compilation errors? What is DBEngine? You are calling `add()` from `AddItemCommand` class, but this class has no such method.

Answer (score 3):

From your error messages it appears that you only have `add` methods for the concrete subclasses, `DiaryItem`, `EventItem`, `StickerItem`, and `TodoItem`, but then you attempt
to call add with an argument of type `T extends AbstractInfoElement`.

That does not work as T ("any subclass of AbstractInfoElement") does not match either of the specific subclasses.

**Edit:** note that Java only does dispatch on static type (i.e., which of the overloaded methods to call is selected based on the type known at compile-time), so it has no way of knowing if T matches one of the subclasses.

(see e.g., [How does Java method dispatch work with Generics and abstract classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452635/how-does-java-method-dispatch-work-with-generics-and-abstract-classes), [Java Generic / Type Dispatch Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784333/java-generic-type-dispatch-question),
[Method overloading and generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191954/method-overloading-and-generics)
)